# CSS line-height style to button in Firefox (decrease)

Tags: css, firefox

How to decrease offset between text and top border in button. I'm trying to set line-height, but it's not working in Firefox: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QaB7g/)

**CSS:**

```
input[type="button"]
{
    border-color: #D2D2D3 #79797A #4D4D4E #C0C0C1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 7px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 16px;
    background: #d8dadb;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="+" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setting a hard width and height.  Take those out or set them to auto and your button will respond to padding adjustments.

```
input[type="button"]
{
    border-color: #D2D2D3 #79797A #4D4D4E #C0C0C1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    line-height: 7px;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #d8dadb;
}​
```

Comment: Unless the element is set to `display: block` (which I don't see in this declaration, but I suppose it could be set from elsewhere), the height/width will be ignored on inline elements.

Comment: Yes, but it's desirable to make a button that is 2 pixels smaller

Comment: *without image in button background

Comment: @Dimitry - You can also reduce the size of the font if you need to make the button even smaller.

Comment: Sorry, 4 pixels smaller (overall 16px height)

Comment: @Lokase Found some Firefox button-styling bug description: http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/ , but that solution usable to increase height...

Answer (score 1):

Firefox bug *(feature)*

http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/

This could help a little:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {border: 0; padding: 0;}
```